# Using a generic Swift class in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, generics

Let's say I define a generic class in Swift, similar to the following:

```
class MyArray<T> {
    func addObject(object: T) {
        // do something... hopefully
    }
}
```

(I know there is a *slightly* better implementation of array, this is merely an example.)

In Swift I can now use this class very easily:

```
let a = MyArray<String>()
a.addObject("abc")
```

[With Xcode 7, we now have generics in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html), so I would assume that I could use this class in Objective-C:

```
MyArray<NSString*> *a = [[MyArray<NSString*> alloc] init];
[a addObject:@"abc"];
```

However, MyArray is never added to my `Project-Swift.h` file. Even if I change it to inherit from NSObject, it still doesn't appear in my Swift.h file.

Is there any way to create a generic Swift class and then use it in Objective-C?

---

**Update:** If I try to inherit from NSObject and annotate with @objc:

```
@objc(MyArray)
class MyArray<T>: NSObject {
    func addObject(object: T) {
        // do something... hopefully
    }
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

> Generic subclasses of '@objc' classes cannot have an explicit '@objc' attribute because they are not directly visible from Objective-C.

Does this mean there is no way to use a generic Swift class in Objective-C?

How does one in*directly* reference the class?

Comment: Did you annotate your class with an @objc?

Comment: @MrBeardsley I just tried it and it gave an interesting compiler error (see above).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Swift generic types cannot be used in Objective-C.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID136

> This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed here:
>
> - Generics
> - ...

Comment: Was that document updated for Xcode 7? Since there are now generics in Objective-C, wouldn't it not be considered a Swift-only feature?

Comment: @Senseful: Lightweight generics in Objective-C are different from and much more limited than Swift generics.

Comment: @newacct do you know a webpage that describes the limitations?

Comment: The list of Swift-only exclusions is removed in the documentation for Swift 2.2.

Answer (score 9):

There is a workaround for some situations, when you need to import Swift generic class into Objective-C.

Let's say you have Swift REST service, which uses Generics. I'm using `Moya` framework and that's how my service looks like:

```
 class AuthService: BaseService<AuthAPI> {
    func register(email: String)  {
       // ... 
    }
 }
```

It's inherited from base service using generics, so I can not use it directly in my Objective-C code.

So here is a workaround:

Lets create `AuthServiceProtocol`:

```
@objc protocol AuthServiceProtocol {
    func register(email: String)
}
```

Then let's create a factory for service (or a singleton method, no difference):

```
@objc class Services: NSObject {
    static let authService: AuthServiceProtocol = AuthService()
}
```

Then I'm able to call my generic Swift auth service from Objective-C code:

```
- (void)someObjcMethod {
    [Services.authService registerWithEmail:self.email];
}
```

Comment: I successfully call the Services in my obj-c class But it gives error when i tried to use authService. "Property 'authService' not found on object of type 'Services ". Plese help me out to solve this issue

Comment: Do you have to do `class AuthService: BaseService<AuthAPI>, AuthServiceProtocol` ?

Comment: what if a registerWithEmail wants to return some kind of generic class :)