# Use generic extended swift class in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, generics

In my project i have many swift classes that extend generic classes. And Now i'm in a need to send data from objective-c class to these swift classes. Is there any possible way to do this ?

I have tried using @objc before class as shown below
[image: image 1]
but it didn't allow me to do this.

I followed this answer [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45057089/4955401). But i checked when i run my app with this code it dint create the variable in the Project-swift class as shown in below image [image: image 2]
as the variable is not created here so it gives error while calling the variable in objective-c class.

Kindly help out with better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution by creating another class which contain a protocol and i indirectly call the generic extended class.

```
class EntityDataTable :BaseData<EntitySw> {
}
```

this is the generic extended class

and the another class i made to indirectly access this class in objective-c is

```
@objc class EntityService : NSObject {
 var entityProtocol:EntityDataProtocol?

 override init() {
    super.init()
    entityProtocol = returnDataObject()
 }

  func returnDataObject() -> EntityDataTable {
    return EntityDataTable()
  }
 }

@objc protocol EntityDataProtocol{
  func addFromService(source: CWEntity)
  func getAll() -> [EntitySw]
}
```

Then i imported the Project-swift.h file in objective c class and made the object of swift class